# attributed string issue in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I am using below extension to convert HTML string to attributed string, to render the attributed string I am using `UILabel`. Font family is system-regular with points 15/18 for iPhone/iPad resp. In above Imgs, **Description** is the caption and attributed string is the value.

```
extension NSAttributedString {

    internal convenience init?(html: String, font : UIFont) {

        let modifiedFont = String(format:"<span style=\"font-family: '-apple-system', '\(font.fontName)'; font-size: \(font.pointSize)\">%@</span>", html)

        guard let data = modifiedFont.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) else {
            return nil
        }

        self.init(attributedString: attributedString)
    }
}
```

console print of variables in above extension

```
(lldb) po html
"<p><font size=\"2\">Pack Size: 2.5 Gal x 2</font></p><p><font size=\"2\">Gallons per case / bucket / barrel:</font></p><p><font size=\"2\">1 Case – 5.0 Gal<br>&nbsp;2 Cases – 10.0 Gal<br>&nbsp;3 Cases – 15.0 Gal</font></p>"

(lldb) po font
<UICTFont: 0x7ffbe4b03a20> font-family: ".SFUI-Regular"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 15.00pt


(lldb) po modifiedFont
"<span style=\"font-family: \'-apple-system\', \'.SFUI-Regular\'; font-size: 15.0\"><p><font size=\"2\">Pack Size: 2.5 Gal x 2</font></p><p><font size=\"2\">Gallons per case / bucket / barrel:</font></p><p><font size=\"2\">1 Case – 5.0 Gal<br>&nbsp;2 Cases – 10.0 Gal<br>&nbsp;3 Cases – 15.0 Gal</font></p></span>"
```

I am calling extension like below

```
self.lblValueDescription.attributedText = NSAttributedString(html: data.descriptionField,
                                                                     font: self.lblValueDescription.font)
```

**Output in iOS 12**

> [image]

**Output in iOS 13**

> [image]

**Issue:**

1. Font size is not same as expected in iOS12
2. iOS13 have some alien characters with same html string.

Comment: There was previously an issue where the font size was wrongly interpreted (could be seen from a loop of (NSAttributedString -> HTML). Seems to be a legacy change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Solutions its working on Both ios 12 and 13 on my side may be its help you.

```
extension String
{
 func htmlAttributed(family: String?, size: CGFloat, colorHex: String) -> NSAttributedString?
  {
    do {
        let htmlCSSString = "<style>" +
            "html *" +
            "{" +
            "font-size: \(size)pt !important;" +
             "color: " + "\(colorHex)" + " !important;" +
            "font-family: \(family ?? "Helvetica"), Helvetica !important;" +
        "}</style> \(self)"

        guard let data = htmlCSSString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
            return nil
        }

        return try NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                      options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                      documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
        print("error: ", error)
        return nil
    }
  }
}
```

And Set Text by this line

```
 self.lblValueDescription.attributedText = yourHtmlString.htmlAttributed(family: "Roboto-Regular", size: 11,colorHex: "#000000")!
```

> **Edit:**

After Reviewing answer I made below changed

```
 let modifiedFont = String(format:"<style>html *{font-family: '-apple-system', '\(font.fontName)' !important; font-size: \(font.pointSize) !important}</style>%@", html)
```

- Modify style tag with the style block
- `!important` flag added to forcily applying the style.

Comment: This is using `utf8` instead of `utf16` encoding like I mentioned below. I believe that's the crucial part of making this work.

Answer (score 0):

This smells of an encode/decode mismatch. You're explicitly specifying `utf16` for your data encoding. However, because of [this](https://swift.org/blog/utf8-string/), you may be having conflicting encodings. That would also explain the garbled characters and the iOS 12 vs 13 issue.